# issues with downloading a static pdf through expressjs - would love some guidance

Tags: express

i don't know if this needed
using cloudflare and iptables to redirect to defualt port
-not running a ngix

-i am using this to write the pdf to directory

```
fs.writeFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname,  "/pdfs", "2312312312.pdf"),
        doc.output(),
        "binary"
      );
```

and this when i start the server the (pdfs directory already exsits).

```
app.use("/pdfs", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "pdfs")));
```

My issue that on some devices it working and on some it giving 404 error

in some it is downloading the file but still giving a 404, different devices give different result